# JNDI lookup is not happening when we bind object in one project and look up from second

Tags: java, jndi

I have two java projects, `Test1` and `Test2`, in `Test1` project I have a servlet with the below code

```
InitialContext initialContext=new InitialContext();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lntdb","root","root");
initialContext.bind("conn", connection);
response.getWriter().println("Bound to JNDI "+initialContext.lookup("conn"));`
```

the above code is binding `MYSQL` database connection object to `JNDI` with name `conn`, then from `Test2` project I am trying to retrieve the connection object. `Test2` also having a servlet with below code

```
InitialContext initialContext=new InitialContext();
response.getWriter().println(initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/conn"));
```

But I am getting exception the stack trace is below

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [conn] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [conn].
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
>       at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lnt.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:19)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   `

Could you tell what is wrong in my code and why I am not able to retrieve connection object

Comment: please share tomcat configuration as well where you have declared jndi name as well.

Comment: I am not not using any jndi.properties. Because the code is running in the server itself, I am using Apache tomcat 7

Comment: share jndi.properties as well. Are you sure that server/application is picking it?

Comment: I am not using any JNDI properties because I am using servlet to connect to JNDI, both will run on same apache tomcat server

Comment: How you can bind as its read only context provided by tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not using any particular context which is common to both application.
In JNDI there is seperate context for all the applications, and what objects your are binding in the first application are blow to the context of first application which are not available to any other applications initial context.

You can follow the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/objects/storing/) to know internals

Comment: *In the java: namespace* there is a separate context *per container instance,* unless the container federated them. It's not correct to assert that as a general statement about JNDI. In an LDAP or RMI or COSNaming namespace it is not the case at all. There is nothing in your citation that supports your claim, and in any case it's a tutorial, not a normative reference.